# How to turn on the hotspot remotely (e.g. bluetooth)?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, bluetooth

I have a MacBook and an iPhone around. On the ground I have no phone signal, therefore there's no way to turn the hotspot on.

I put my iPhone on a long piece of wood and bring it in the air at a height of ~6 meters. There my iPhone gets phone signal and internet.

Is it possible to turn the hotspot on using some kind of bluetooth communication from the ground level?

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can turn on the hotspot from the MacBook by choosing the phone in the WiFi menu, where it is displayed with a special icon. The feature is called "Instant Hotspot" and is accomplished using Bluetooth.

1. sign in to iCloud on both devices
2. Enable continuity (a.k.a. Handoff) on both - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681
3. Enable wifi and Bluetooth on both macOS and iOS

This requires you to be using the same AppleID on the phone as on the MacBook. You'll also need at least iOS 8.1 on the phone and OS X Yosemite or later on the MacBook.

If you open System Report on your Mac and select "Bluetooth", it should be listed whether Instant Hotspot is supposed by your hardare.

Comment: How can I make sure my phone bluetooth is *seen*  by the MacBook? Last time when I tried no phone was visible in the wifi menu, even the bluetooth was activated.

Comment: Test it on the ground before you place the phone in the air. If it works there, it's a range problem.

Comment: I guess if the phone hotspot is not active, it won't even appear in the menu. I don't think it's a range problem.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I'm editing the answer to have more steps. If you have range issues, it's either external Bluetooth interference or it is a hardware malfunction. Handoff in this case works for me at ranges of 10 meters or so usually. How long is your "stick"?

Comment: Hopefully I can mark the answer, once this setup will work. Haha! :D It's hard to test right now because I'm on the top of a hill where I have good signal anyways. So, what are you saying is that the iPhone should appear there even the hotspot is disabled, as long the phone bluetooth is active?

Comment: @IonicăBizău No, the hotspot does not have to be active for it to appear in the menu. That's the point of Instant Hotspot - to be able to activate the hotspot from the Mac instead of from the phone.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Exactly, yes

Comment: Yes @IonicăBizău - you can test continuity with no wifi connection at all. You need to take everything to a working network to set up continuity. Keys exchange to Apple server. Read the apple KB carefully and follow all setup steps, in order. You likely didn't complete #2 fully.

Comment: That worked. I think it was because I used hotspot for the first time with this prepay sim. I was saying *Please contact your carrier* before. Then after using hotspot in a place with a stronger signal, now it is working here as well. This very message was sent via my improvised *antenna* which uses my iPhone: http://i.imgur.com/HiRgAZV.jpg 

Comment: Just a small update after few days: it turns out that before going in this area where there's no signal, I have to use the hotspot once, after switching the SIM cards. Only the first time it says to contact the carrier—not sure why.